# Is there a way to tag a root volume when initializing from the cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am creating an instance through the cloud formation script.

The only way I found to attach an OS partition was through "BlockDeviceMappings" property. (I've tried to use "Volumes" property before, but the instance could not be mounted, the system told me that /dev/sda was already mapped and rolled back the instance creation)

Here is the relevant portion of my template:

```
  "Resources" :
  {
    "Ec2Instance" :
    {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" :
      {
        "BlockDeviceMappings" :
        [{
          "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda",
          "Ebs" :
          {
            "VolumeSize" : { "Ref" : "RootVolumeSize" },
            "SnapshotId" :
            { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap",
              { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "RootVolumeSnapshotId" ]
            }
          }
        }],
        ...
       }
     }
```

My question is, how can I tag the Ebs volume, that I am creating here with "BlockDeviceMappings" property?  I did not find the obvious solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that from March 2017, you can tag volumes at create time from the AWS Web Console http://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=9m7m53y9ci90nd0ocjs2svfen (but not yet CloudFormation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was able to make it work through an AWS CLI interface, IAM role, and UserData initialization.

Added this to `AWS::EC2::Instance:Properties:UserData`

```
{ "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "\n", [
  "#!/bin/bash",
  "set -eux",
  "exec > >(tee /tmp/user-data.log | logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1",
  { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [
    "AWS_STACK_NAME='", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" }, "'"
  ]]},
  { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [
    "AWS_ROOT_VOLUME_SNAPSHOT_ID='",
      { "Fn::FindInMap" :
         [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "RootVolumeSnapshotId" ]},
      "'"
  ]]},
  "AWS_INSTANCE_ID=$( curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id )",
  "",
  "AWS_HOME=/opt/aws",
  "AWS_BIN_DIR=\"${AWS_HOME}/bin\"",
  "export EC2_HOME=\"${AWS_HOME}/apitools/ec2\"",
  "export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0",
  "",
  "ROOT_DISK_ID=$(",
  "    \"${AWS_BIN_DIR}/ec2-describe-volumes\" \\",
  "        --filter \"attachment.instance-id=${AWS_INSTANCE_ID}\" \\",
  "        --show-empty-fields \\",
  "      | grep '^VOLUME' \\",
  "      | awk '{printf \"%s,%s\\n\", $4, $2}' \\",
  "      | grep '^${AWS_ROOT_VOLUME_SNAPSHOT_ID}' \\",
  "      | cut --delimiter=, --fields=2",
  "    exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}",
  "  )",
  "\"${AWS_BIN_DIR}/ec2-create-tags \\",
  "  \"${ROOT_DISK_ID}\" \\",
  "  --tag \"Name=${AWS_STACK_NAME}-root\"",
  ""
]]}}
```

Also have to add a reference to an IAM role that can describe volumes and create tags.

Added this to "Resources" section:

```
"InstanceProfile" :
{
  "Type" : "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
  "Properties" :
  {
    "Path" : "/",
    "Roles" : [ "ec2-tag-instance" ]
  }
}
```

Referenced this profile in the `Instance` resource:

```
"Ec2Instance" :
{
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties" :
  {
    ...
    "IamInstanceProfile" : {"Ref" : "InstanceProfile"},
    ...
  }
}
```

And in `IAM` UI create a new Role called `ec2-tag-instance`, and assign this policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*",
        "ec2:CreateTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This said, would be much nicer if `BlockDeviceMappings:Ebs` had supported `Tags` element.

Comment: FWIW, I created a feature request for adding tagging support BlockDeviceMappings:Ebs, it might help you did the same.

Comment: @BillMan.  Can you paste the link with feature request?  I will upvote it.

Comment: @BillMan Do you have the link with the feature request for us? I´m looking forward to this feature because it´s much simpler than this solution above with the "UserData" part.

Comment: The suggested IAM policy may be overly permissive for some use-cases, in that it allows any EC2 resource tags to be created or overwritten. If your instance is compromised, it can thus create havoc if you use tags for other purposes (e.g. managing EC2 EBS snapshots).

Answer (score 1):

If your CloudFormation stack is tagged and you want your EC2 attached volumes to copy over the tags from the stack you can use the below UserData value.

```
Fn::Base64: !Sub |
    #!/bin/bash -xe
    exec > /tmp/part-001.log 2>&1
    # --==Tagging Attached Volumes==--
    TAGS=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${AWS::StackName} --query 'Stacks[0].Tags' --region ${AWS::Region})
    EC2_INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
    EBS_IDS=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values="$EC2_INSTANCE_ID" --region ${AWS::Region} --query 'Volumes[*].[VolumeId]' --out text | tr "\n" " ")
    aws ec2 create-tags --resources $EBS_IDS --tags "$TAGS" --region ${AWS::Region}
    TAGS=$(echo $TAGS | tr "Key" "key" | tr "Value" "value")
    aws ecs tag-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:ecs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:cluster/${EcsClusterName} --tags "$TAGS"
```

1. Write all stdout and stderr to file for debugging:

   `exec > /tmp/part-001.log 2>&1
2. (requires permission) Get the tags from the stack:

   `TAGS=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name ${AWS::StackName} --query 'Stacks[0].Tags' --region ${AWS::Region})`
3. Get the EC2 instance id from the metadata endpoint:

   `EC2_INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)`
4. (requires permission) Get the EBS IDS:

   `EBS_IDS=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values="$EC2_INSTANCE_ID" --region ${AWS::Region} --query 'Volumes[*].[VolumeId]' --out text | tr "\n" " ")`
5. (requires permission) Add tags to the EBS volumes: 
   `aws ec2 create-tags --resources $EBS_IDS --tags "$TAGS" --region ${AWS::Region}`
6. Format tags for ECS tagging:

   `TAGS=$(echo $TAGS | tr "Key" "key" | tr "Value" "value")`
7. (requires permission) Tag the ECS cluster:

   `aws ecs tag-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:ecs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:cluster/${EcsClusterName} --tags "$TAGS"`

**The policy should look like this:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ecs:TagResource", 
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CloudFormation template to create resources like CloudWatch event rule and Lambda. The lambda invocation can get triggered not only when there is instance creation event but when updates happen to instance tags.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did in my ec2 userdata. I think it's much simpler than above answer.

```
Key=<Your Tag Name>
Value=<Your Tag Value>
Region=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | grep -oP "(?<=\"region\" : \")[^\"]+")

aws ec2 create-tags --resources $(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --region $Region | grep -oP "(?<=\"VolumeId\": \")[^\"]+") --tags Key=$Key,Value=$Value --region $Region
```

Comment: Question was about how to do this from the CloudFormation template.  If you look at the template in my answer you will see that it does exactly this.